# Videos Uploaded to YouTube play the music but not the voice

Tags: youtube, mobile

We uploaded several videos to YouTube and have recently found that they are not playing correctly on mobile YouTube. You can hear the music but not the voices. We have tried editing using iMovie and Final Cut Pro X. The audio is fine on desktops. How can we fix this?

This is our YouTube Channel:
http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOcYPVNUlvDnzBFuyg_fzkw